# Abrir Relatório Access com Critério

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Sou iniciante em *C#* e estou abrindo um relatório do *Access*, porém este relatório possui critério, ou seja, depende de uma numeração para abrir.

Esta numeração possuo em uma *textbox* e minha dúvida é como passar o valor desta *textbox* direto para o relatório do *Access* quando ele for aberto.

Segue o código que utilizo para abrir o relatório:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();         accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"E:\Desenvolvimento\C#\ReciboFácil\ReciboFácil\bin\Debug\ReciboFacil.mdb");
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenReport("ReciboServiço");
accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
accessApp.DoCmd.Quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver. Alterei o código da seguinte forma:

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application accessApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();         accessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"E:\Desenvolvimento\C#\ReciboFácil\ReciboFácil\bin\Debug\ReciboFacil.mdb");
accessApp.DoCmd.OpenReport("ReciboServiço", AcView.acViewNormal,"", "[codrecibo]=" + codrecibo);
accessApp.CloseCurrentDatabase();
accessApp.DoCmd.Quit();`

Comment: Marca como respondida sua questão.